# Преобразовать byte[] в объект

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

На входе есть строка, которую необходимо преобразовать в объект. Делаю так

```
byte[] file = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sign);
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf 
= new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file);
ms.Position = 0;
object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
```

Получаю ошибку

> Недопустимый двоичный формат входного потока. Начало содержимого (в
>   байтах):

Если сохраняю в файл

```
File(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sign), "application/text", name)
```

то получаю файл, который проходит проверку без ошибок.

Comment: А если сделать как нибудь так? 'var tn = new TreeNode();
var node1 = tn.Nodes.Add("123");
node1.Nodes.Add("123");
node1.Nodes.Add("123");
node1.Nodes.Add("123");
node1.Nodes.Add("123");
 
using (var fs = File.Create("test.bin"))
{
    new BinaryFormatter().Serialize(fs, tn);
    fs.Flush();
}
 
using (var fs = File.Open("test.bin", FileMode.Open))
{
    var node = (TreeNode)new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(fs);
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
}'

Comment: Так и не понял, как вставить код в коментарий.

Comment: @QuaternioNoir при чем тут TreeNode?

Comment: @QuaternioNoir большие куски кода в комментариях не уместны, а маленькие достаточно обернуть в "`" - те что на одной клавише с тильдой

Comment: @e1s, А зачем Вы это делаете? Конечно то что Вы написали работать не будет, потому что Вы пытаетесь непонятно что десериализовать не понятно что в что-то. Возьмите сериализуйте `BinaryFormatter'ом`, и потом спокойно десериализуйте.

Comment: `byte[] file = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sign);`   `object obj = file;`

может вы это имеете ввиду?